# python deprecated pd.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True) works the alternative one malfunctions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The following warning is thrown but i am getting the actual intended result ,when i try to change the code it fails.

```
new_table = new_table.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
new_table=new_table.replace(np.nan,0)  # This is used to make - to 0 for calc
```

Warning (from warnings module):
new_table = new_table.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
FutureWarning: convert_objects is deprecated.  Use the data-type specific converters pd.to_datetime, pd.to_timedelta and pd.to_numeric.

the new_table is nothing but a pandas dataframe it contains

```
A    B   C  D  E
1    -   3  5  6
2    3   5  6  7
-    -   5  5  5
5    4   -  -  -
-    -   4  -  4
9    -   -  10 23
```

In this given data frame format since we have the string "-" further sum or diff or multiplication logics throws error if i use the below method .

```
new_table = pd.to_numeric(new_table)
#new_table=new_table.replace("-",0)
new_table=new_table.replace(np.nan,0)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File  line 107, in 
    new_table = pd.to_numeric(new_table)
  File  line 113, in to_numeric
    raise TypeError('arg must be a list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series')
TypeError: arg must be a list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series

What is the best way of handling this situation the first row shall be index in str format and others rows are numeric so that my arithmatic calculation will not be affected.

Any help ?

Comment: So how working my solutions?

Comment: I will check and feedback ,Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can if need replace all non numeric values to `NaN`s use `apply` for working with columns in `df` with function [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html), then to `0` by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) and last all values to `int`s by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
new_table1 = new_table.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype(int)
print (new_table1)
   A  B  C   D   E
0  1  0  3   5   6
1  2  3  5   6   7
2  0  0  5   5   5
3  5  4  0   0   0
4  0  0  4   0   4
5  9  0  0  10  23

print (new_table1.dtypes)
A    int32
B    int32
C    int32
D    int32
E    int32
dtype: object
```

Anoter solution if all values are integers is [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) all non numbers + [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
new_table2 = new_table.replace('\D+', 0, regex=True).astype(int)
print (new_table2)
   A  B  C   D   E
0  1  0  3   5   6
1  2  3  5   6   7
2  0  0  5   5   5
3  5  4  0   0   0
4  0  0  4   0   4
5  9  0  0  10  23

print (new_table2.dtypes)
A    int32
B    int32
C    int32
D    int32
E    int32
dtype: object
```

And if all values are only `-` then solution is simplifying:

```
new_table3 = new_table.replace('-', 0, regex=True).astype(int)
print (new_table3)
   A  B  C   D   E
0  1  0  3   5   6
1  2  3  5   6   7
2  0  0  5   5   5
3  5  4  0   0   0
4  0  0  4   0   4
5  9  0  0  10  23

print (new_table3.dtypes)
A    int32
B    int32
C    int32
D    int32
E    int32
dtype: object
```

Comment: new_table1 = new_table.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype(int)  this solved my logic issue and the warning is gone away now.

Comment: Super, glad can help! You are still better in pandas ;)

Comment: Really nice logics and lot of learning in python pandas ,it is an ocean

Comment: Yes, I remember these days, I was astonished too;)

Comment: oh my god ,if index as Date is there this above-given solution replaces that as well to int so the Date index becomes 0 .How to avoid this.